# Uninstall does not remove registy entries

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

I have created two MSIs(mypkg1.0.0 & mypkg2.0.0) with different product codes and versions. The two MSIs are creating below registry entries respectively during installation. The component codes of two MSIs which are creating registry keys are same.

mypkg1.0.0

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\{companyname}\1.0
```

mypkg2.0.0

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\{companyname}\2.0
```

I have installed two MSIs successfully and above registry entries got created. If I uninstall any of the two installed MSIs , the respective registry key is not getting removed. The registry key is getting removed only for the last uninstalled MSI.

Scenario: 1
**mypkg2.0.0 uninstall, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node{companyname}\2.0  => Not removed**

**mypkg1.0.0 uninstall, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node{companyname}\1.0  => Removed**

Scenario: 2
**mypkg1.0.0 uninstall, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node{companyname}\1.0  => Not removed**

**mypkg2.0.0 uninstall, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node{companyname}\2.0  => Removed**

Why the registry key is not removed if two packages are installed. Do we need to change the component code though product code and version are different?

Comment: If you create the registry key you have to delete the registry key.  The only way these keys are being created is if you created them in the first place.  An application does not have to use the registry to function, most applications, do not use the registry at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you have developed own software and has built a installer and trying to install it then you have to go through the source code why it does not working properly. Further please include in detail to submit proper answer.

The registry keys adding by registry editing from a software so if it's not working properly there may have issues at registry.